# StreamDensityPlot

Tags: plotting, graphics

```
Table[
  StreamDensityPlot[{y, μ y + x - x^2 + x y}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3},
    PlotLabel -> Row[{"μ = ", μ}], StreamScale -> 0.2, StreamStyle -> Black
  ], 
  {μ, {-0.958, -0.9300, -0.9100, -0.8900, -0.8700,  -0.8650, -0.8646, -0.9500}}
]
```

I used the above code for system `[{y, μ y + x - x^2 + x y}]`

I just want determine the solution on figure , x and y solution's , but I don't Know How I do it.

Answer (score 2):

The appropriate functionality you are looking for is `Manipulate` which takes discrete values.

```
Manipulate[StreamDensityPlot[{y, μ y + x - x^2 + x y}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 
   3}, PlotLabel -> Row[{"μ = ", μ}], StreamScale -> 0.2, StreamStyle -> Black], 
{μ, {-0.958, -0.9300, -0.9100, -0.8900, -0.8700, -0.8650, -0.8646, -0.9500}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Ok, How I can do for every solution on the graph distinct color.